# Scripts param quando abro Modal em uma Partial View pela segunda vez

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, modal

Minha primeira questão aqui.

Estou desenvolvendo meu primeiro sistema utilizando Asp.Net MVC.

Em uma View chamo um Modal cujo `modal-content` esta um uma PartialView que contém scripts (jQuery). Quando abro o Modal pela primeira vez tudo ocorre como previsto, mas caso eu feche o Modal e abra novamente os scripts param de responder. 
O `modal-container` coloquei na _Layout, porque assim posso reutilizar em outros Modais.
Na _Layout também tem scripts para os eventos "padrões" dos Modais como o abaixo que limpa o cache para quando um novo modal for carregado:

```
  $('#modal-container').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });
```

Caso eu remova esse evento os scripts funcionam mesmo quando abro o Modal pela segunda vez, mas o Modal fica em cache e ao abrir um novo Modal o primeiro Modal é sempre carregado.

Segue meu código: 
Obs.: Ocultei as partes que considero não relevantes a questão.

### CreateEdit.cshtml

Chama a Action que retorna a PartialViewm

```
                        <div class="col-md-1 form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Evento.CodChamada, "Cod Evento.")
                            <div class="input-group">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Evento.CodChamada, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                <a href="@Url.Action("OpenSearchEvento", "Formando")" id="btnSearchEvento" class="modal-link input-group-addon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

### FormandoController.cs

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult OpenSearchEvento(SearchViewModel searchValues)
    {
        var model = GetEventos(searchValues);

        return PartialView("_SearchEvento", model);
    }
```

### SearchEvento.cshtml

```
    $(function () {
        debugger;
        $('#modal-style').css('width', '1250px');
        $('#btnCreate, #actives-only').hide();

        $('#table-eventos tr').on('click', function () {
            $(this).addClass('selected')
                .siblings()
                .removeClass('selected')
                .css('font-weight', 'normal');

            var selectedSearchItem = $(this).find('td:first').html();
            $('.selected').css('font-weight', 'bold');

        });

        $('#btnSelectEvento').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var codChamadaEvento = $('#table-eventos tr.selected td:eq(0)').text();
            var nomeEvento = $('#table-eventos tr.selected td:eq(1)').text();
            var EventolId = $('#table-eventos tr.selected').find('td:first').attr('data-evento-id');

            if (lastEventoId != EventolId) {

                if ($('#IsControlaRifa').is(':checked')) {
                    bootbox.confirm({
                        title: 'Alterar Evento',
                        message: 'Ao alterar o Evento do Formando Todas as Rifas do Formando serão excluídas',
                        buttons: {
                            cancel: {
                                label: '<i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancelar',
                                className: "btn-default"
                            },
                            confirm: {
                                label: '<i class="fa fa-check"></i> OK',
                                className: "btn-danger"
                            }
                        },
                        callback: function (result) {
                            if (result) {
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: '/Formando/DeleteAllRifasFormando',
                                    ajaxasync: true,
                                    cache: false,
                                    method: 'POST',
                                    data: { id: formandoId },
                                    datatype: "text/html"
                                })
                                    .done(function () {
                                        $('#rifas-evento > tbody').html('');
                                        $($('#tabs').find('li')[3]).hide();
                                        $('#IsControlaRifa').prop('checked', false);
                                        bootbox.alert('As Rifas do Formando foram excluidas com sucesso!');
                                        $('#IsControlaRifa').addClass('readOnly');
                                        $('#btnCreateReset').prop('disabled', true);
                                        $('#btnReturn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                                    })
                                    .fail(function () {
                                        bootbox.alert('O registro não existe!')
                                    });
                            }
                            $('#IsControlaRifa').prop('checked', true);
                            bootbox.hideAll();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            $('#Evento_CodChamada').val(codChamadaEvento);
            $('#Evento_NomeEvento').val(nomeEvento);
            $('#EventoId').val(EventolId)

            $('#modal-container').modal('hide');

        });

        $('#btnSearch').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var searchTerm = $('#SearchTerm').val();
            var searchItem = $('#SearchItem').val();
            var isPartial = $('#IsPartial').is(':checked');

            var searchViewModel = {
                'IsPartial': isPartial,
                'IsActivesOnly': true,
                'SearchTerm': searchTerm,
                'SearchItem': searchItem
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Formando/SearchEvento',
                type: 'POST',
                datatype: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify(searchViewModel),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != null && data.length > 0) {

                        for (i in data) {
                            var template = $('#eventotpl').html();
                        }

                        var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);

                        $('#table-eventos tbody')
                            .empty()
                            .html(html);
                    }
                    else
                        bootbox.alert('A pesquisa não retornou resultados!');
                },
                error: function () {
                    bootbox.alert("Não foi possível Alterar o Contrato do Formando!")
                }
            })
            debugger;
        });

    });
</script>
<script id="eventotpl" type="text/template">
    {{#.}}
    <tr>

        <td class="rv-cod-chamada" data-evento-id={{Id}}>{{CodChamada}}</td>
        <td>{{NomeEvento}}</td>
        <td class="rv-active-icon">{{#IsControlaRifa}} <span><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></i></span> 
                    {{/IsControlaRifa}} {{^IsControlaRifa}} <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i></td> {{/IsControlaRifa}}
    </tr>

    {{/.}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Após muita pesquisa consegui encontrar a solução!

A questão é que quando um modal é criado (chamado pela primeira vez) ele é anexado ao especificado em `data-target`. Quando fechamos e abrimos novamente o modal, somente o método `toggle()` é chamado e portanto o conteúdo do modal não é atualizado.

A solução é então "destruir" o modal antes de uma nova chamada.

No meu caso os scripts paravam de funcionar porque na verdade eles nem eram carregados pois haviam sido "destruidos". Para solucionar, no evento `click`  dos botões que chamam os modais agora passo a `url` que que contém o conteúdo do modal e utilizei o método load para (re)carregar o novo conteúdo.

```
 $('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault()
                var button = $(e.relatedTarget); 
                var url = button.attr("href");
                var modal = $(this);
                modal.find('.modal-content').load(url);
            });
```

Além disso ao destruir o modal, também alterei o código para esvaziar o `modal-content` e agora consigo fechar e abrir o modal e tudo funciona corretamente. Além disso é possível abrir um novo modal com um outro conteúdo.

```
$('#modal-container').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
                $('#modal-container .modal-content').empty();

            });
```